# how to convert the instagram curl post request to javascript request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, curl, instagram-api

I'm trying to change the code i got from Instagram to a token. In Instagram DOCS it is writes with a curl request and i want to use JavaScript.
its look like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
  -F client_id={app-id} \
  -F client_secret={app-secret} \
  -F grant_type=authorization_code \
  -F redirect_uri={redirect-uri} \
  -F code={code}
```

I'm trying to understand what is `-F` and with what symbol to replace it.

Any solution will help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

-F is for emulating html form submission
https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

if you want to sent the request using JavaScript fetch() API, set all those parameters as body of request and set the content type to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

if you are sending these requests interactively,
alternatively you can create an HTML page with a form and submit button.( e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp )

Comment: thank you very much! 
but the request isn't complete. when I tried to print the data i get: 
**'Missing required field client_id'**.
this is my code:
`fetch("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({client_id:{app-id},
client_secret:{app-secret},
grant_type:authorization_code,
redirect_uri:{redirect-uri},
code:{code}}),
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log("data", data));`
and it is working in postman.

Comment: you shouldn't use JSON.stringify(). you are not sending JSON fromat .

you need to send them in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.
e.g. client_id={app-id} ....
see the body of your postman request